# Enabling Prestashop webservices on module install

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to develop a module to sync 2 or more Prestashop stores via webservices. I've made a module skeleton thanks to [this module generator](https://validator.prestashop.com/generator) but now, first steps take me to the question:

How can I auto-switch on webservices on my custom module installation?

Comment: Put the `WebServiceLibrary` in your module and do an 'import' when you have to use it :). [Here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib) you can download the official library

Comment: To autoswitch I think you just need in your `intall()` function to update this value like this  `Configuration::updateValue('PS_WEBSERVICE', true);` But think you will need lot more code in module, to check different conditions. Check `AdminWebServiceController` in `controllers/admin` folder and do check this  [free module](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/504525-free-module-shipix-storage-shipping-smartphone-app-for-prestashop/)

Comment: @sarcom Thanks, but I think that I did not explain well. This library helps me to develope my module using webservices functions but, what I need is enable webservices as you can do it on PS Backend, switching on the button (_Advanced parameters -> Webservices -> Enable Webservices_)

Comment: @PH_Laza Thanks, I'll try and report if works or not :)

Comment: @PH_Laza , your solution worked fine! My answer now is, what you mean when you mention 'more code in module'?

Comment: @Makros Well maybe more code is not needed, I thought on different checks in `AdminWebServiceController.php` function `checkForWarning()` but probably you do not need to worry much about that in your module.

Comment: @PH_Laza Now I've got new questions. Need to know how to add one webservice on install but I think that it'll be better do a new Stack question, isn't it?

Comment: @Makros Yes that would be new question, but do check code in fee module I linked, could give you some idea about it. Also added answer, so it is not in comments.

Comment: Thank you so much @PH_Laza I will take a look =)

Comment: @PH_Laza again, thank you so much, your tip on fee module you told me it's solving some doubts =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To autoswitch web services in PrestaShop I think you just need in your module `install()` function to update `PS_WEBSERVICE` value like this

`Configuration::updateValue('PS_WEBSERVICE', true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line of code to the install() function of your module:

```
Configuration::updateGlobalValue('PS_WEBSERVICE', '1');
```